# Automatic reference counting - using a value elsewhere in the same implementation file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC with TWRequest. I have successfully returned a search from twitter and created an array of the results. Here is my code...

```
NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey:@"results"];

//Loop through the results
NSMutableArray *twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *tweet in results)
{
    // Get the tweet
    NSString *twittext = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

    // Save the tweet to the twitterText array
    [twitterText addObject:twittext];
}
NSLog(@"MY ************************TWITTERTEXT************** %@", twitterText );
```

My question is, I want to use twitterText later in the .m file under cellForRowAtIndexPath but as soon as the loop through (as above) is finished it is being released under ARC.

I have set the property as strong in my .h file (as well as declaring it above just prior to the loop - not sure if I can do that but if I do not declare in as above the twitterText returns NULL).

Printing a log straight after the loop through as above prints the twitterText Array fine but the same Log in cellForRowAtIndex path method returns a blank, almost like it has forgotten it exists. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your variable twitterText in a local context. So ARC is dropping it after the method is done. You should have it declared like this if you'd like to use it outside the scope of that method.

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *twitterText;

.m
@synthesize twitterText = _twitterText; // ivar optional

_twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *tweet in results) {
    // Get the tweet
    NSString *twittext = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

    // Save the tweet to the twitterText array
    [_twitterText addObject:twittext];
}


-(void)someOtherMethod {
    NSLog(@"twitterText: %@", _twitterText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting _twitterText returning "NULL" though. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would try and display what you are getting for [tweet objectForKey:@"text"], my guess is that is empty or null, not your variable.

Comment: Is NSString *twittext actually a valid string? Is there a value there? Just curious what value is returned by [tweet objectForKey:@"text"]. I honestly don't see any issues with it if you adopt my example. Try changing from (strong) to (nonatomic, strong).

Comment: Hi Bill - Nope, still doesn't work. The *twitext works as I can print out both a log of this and twittertext (when the log is placed within the loop through. I've tried the (nonatomic, strong) property declaration and no success either. I am placing _twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in place of where I had NSMutableArray *twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; I'm guessing that is correct? Thanks

Comment: Hi Bill - any builds on the above? Thanks

Comment: Maybe try debugging it stopping it before, and stepping through it. You should be able to see all the values as it is running. See where your items are getting allocated at. There is something weird we aren't seeing. The answers here are right and should work just fine. So something is getting off somewhere.

Comment: Interesting.... There is no mention of twitterText or even _twitterText in the debug console. All the other values are mentioned. I can print twitterText from within that particular method but not in another method?

Comment: Hi Bill after a bit more delving and stepping through it seems that _twittertext is being dumped after the loop through. Even though I have followed what you have said above. The message I'm getting is "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'" meaning that_twitterText is empty when it gets to the cellforrowatindexpath method. Any other thoughts? Thanks very much

Comment: Do this, move the alloc/init of twitterText to your -viewDidLoad.

Comment: Hi Bill - that is where it is at the moment. I I put it anywhere else it returns NULL........

Comment: You should only have it in one spot. Any more than that will cause ARC to release the old object and create a new instance. No bueno.

Comment: Hi Bill - it is only in one spot, in the viewdidload and always has been. Do I really need to use twitterText = _twitterText; when i synthesize? i have set twitterText as strong, nonatomic in my .h file so I can't understand why it is dropped?

Answer (score 0):

Make `NSMutableArray *twitterText` `@property` to be as public because it's sure will released after the end of life cycle of the function.
In case there is no ARC retain it will work fine and it's worked for me.
Edited
Try
.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *twitterText;
```

.m

```
@synthesize twitterText = _twitterText;
```

in "ViewDidLoad" delegate make

```
self.twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

in your function make

```
for (NSDictionary *tweet in results)
{
    [self.twitterText addObject:[tweet objectForKey:@"text"]];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "make it public"? Thanks. I'm using ARC so cannot use 'retain'

Comment: yes i know i said if you don't use ARC make retain if ARC make @property and by default the object will be retained in ARC mode

Comment: Hi, I have done that - I mentioned that "I have set the property as strong in my .h file" as well as declaring an instance in my .m file - still not working though

Comment: if you do so and making NSMutableArray *twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; so you have duplicate values with the same name one local and one public so you need to make only public and initialize it in "ViewDidLoad" twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; and use it directly in your method with  "twitterText addobject" without the first line of  "NSMutableArray *twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]" in the function..

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. If I do not declare it in my .h file I get errors wherever twitterText is mentioned in the .m file, even when I decare it in viewDidLoad

Comment: Hi Mina, can I ask why you would  have _twitterText;
 as it is not used anywhere in your code? Thanks

Comment: Hi Mina - any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Sorry regarding your question i can't help you.. this is the best way that we all do i think that you have another issue or you dealloc the object somewhere else before you call it again so it's returns null make watch on "self.twitterText retain count" to see who access it and released it before you call it again...